# Uploaded image (base64) looks corrupted in firebase putString method

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am uploading an image(base64) to firebase with putString method

```
uploadTask = fireStorage.ref('/your/path/here').child('file_name').putString(snapshot, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpg' });
```

Its a valid base64 content (since its a huge string that's why I can paste it here. But I have already checked it by decoding it to image online) But it starts something like this

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAkACQAAD/4QCMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQES`

The uploaded(to firebase) image looks empty like a box of 1pixel.

This is the URL image

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/manage-my-rides-1493889860531.appspot.com/o/lala%2Fchild.jpg?alt=media&token=63c9078a-7124-41a1-9349-6a2f2c6d8379

Code of firebase

```
var uploadedFile = await fireStorage.ref("lala").child("child.jpg").putString(snapshot, 'base64', {
        contentType: 'image/jpg'
    });
var url = await fireStorage.ref("lala").child("child.jpg").getDownloadURL();
    console.log(url);
```

Comment: Try removing `data:image/jpeg;base64`, part from your string, if it is there

Comment: @PritishVaidya Its not there. Updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried setting the `base64` using various methods and it doesn't seem to work. *The image gets seems to get corrupted during storage*

Here's a quick **workaround**

```
fetch(YOUR_ORIGINAL_BASE_64_STRING)
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => 
      fireStorage.ref('/your/path/here').child('file_name').put(blob);
    )
```

**Example**

```
var url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('image');
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob =>
        storageRef.put(blob).then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot)
            console.log('Uploaded a blob!');
        })
    )
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough. You are awesome. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/manage-my-rides-1493889860531.appspot.com/o/your%2Fpath%2Fhere%2Ffile_name?alt=media&token=9a38b378-8420-498f-92e4-9714cd65e9d7